# Sudoku infinite loop using stacks

Tags: c++, sudoku

I'm new and have not coded C++ in well over five years. I have a project in a class about a sudoku solver. It works (for the most part) except when it backtracks (when it can't find a single possible value to put in the box) it either backtracks all the way to the beginning or fails to get out of the loop. Help? Code is below

```
Address::Address(int row, int col) //This class is for the addresses of each block of of the 9x9 grid
{
    this->row=row;
    this->col=col;
}//finds the locations of each block

Puzzle::Puzzle(const char grid[][9])
{
}

void Puzzle::solve(char grid[][9])
{
stack <Address> locations; //creates stack of locations
for(int row=0; row<9;row++)
{
    for (int col=0; col<9; col++)
    {
        if (grid[row][col]=='*') //checks for an empty block
        {
            Possibles possibles(grid,Address(row,col)); //creates an array of possible values for that specific block
            int possvalue = possibles.GetNextPossible(0); //gets the next possible value from the array of possible values
            while(possvalue == -1) //checks if there's no possible values for the block 
            {
                if(locations.empty())
                {
                    cout << "Puzzle Unsolvable" << endl;
                    return;
                }
                cout<<"PossValue before: "<< possvalue <<endl;
                Address previouslocation = locations.top(); //stores the previous location from the stack
                Possibles previouspossible(grid,previouslocation); //creates a new array of new possibles
                previouspossible.array[grid[previouslocation.row][previouslocation.col]-'0'] = false;
                grid[previouslocation.row][previouslocation.col] = '*'; //changes the previous location back to empty
                possvalue = previouspossible.GetNextPossible(grid[previouslocation.row][previouslocation.col]-'0'); //gets the new possible value from new possibles
                locations.pop();


                cout<<"PossValue after: "<< possvalue<<endl;
                cout<<"row: "<< row<<endl;
                cout<<"col: "<< col<<endl;
                cout<<"previouslocation.row: "<< previouslocation.row<<endl;
                cout<<"previouslocation.col: "<< previouslocation.col<<endl;
                cout<<"previousvalue" << grid[previouslocation.row][previouslocation.col] << endl;
                cout<<"grid[previouslocation.row][previouslocation.col]: "<< grid[previouslocation.row][previouslocation.col]<<endl;
                cout << locations.size() << endl;
                cout<<endl;

                row = previouslocation.row; //changes the row where we're trying to solve
                col = previouslocation.col; //changes the column where we're trying to solve
            }

            grid[row][col] = (char) ( ((int)'0') + possvalue); //puts the "good" value on the grid
            locations.push (Address(row,col)); // pushes the location of the box into the stack
            /*for(int i = 0; i< 9; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j< 9; j++)
                    cout << grid[i][j];

                    cout << endl;
            }*/ // for row
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

}//solves sudoku

Possibles::Possibles(char grid[][9], Address currentAddress) //makes an array for each block for the number of possibles
{
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
        array[i] = true; //setting a boolean array of size 9 to true
}

for (int row=0; row<9;row++)
{
array[grid[row][currentAddress.col]-'0'] = false; //checks for repeated values on the row 
}
for(int col=0; col<9; col++)
{
    array[grid[currentAddress.row][col]-'0'] = false; //checks for repeated values on the column
}
for(int row=currentAddress.row-(currentAddress.row%3); row < (currentAddress.row-(currentAddress.row%3))+3 ; row++) 
{
    for(int col=currentAddress.col-(currentAddress.col%3); col < (currentAddress.col-(currentAddress.col%3))+3 ; col++)
    {
        array[grid[row][col]-'0'] = false; //checks for repeated values in the box
    }
}

}//this function returns an array of "possibles" which is a boolean array for every value from 1-9. This determines whether the value is a possibility for that block.

int Possibles::GetNextPossible(int nextpossible) //determines the next "possible" array
{
for(int i=nextpossible+1; i<10; i++)
{
    if (array[i] == true)
        {
            return i; //if the boolean array returns true, then return the value of that boolean array.
        }
}
return -1; // if there is no "true" in the boolean array, then returns "NULL"
}
```

THanks for the help, guys! Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Are you possibly giving it Sudoku problems that are unsolvable?

Comment: To prevent infinite loops, you need some condition that guarantees you'll stop. For example, if you traverse all solutions according to a predefined ordering, and your loop is monotonic (say always increasing) in the ordering, then it must terminate. (Similarly for recursion, this is the standard way to make sure you bottom out.)

Comment: @NicholasWilson Doing backtracking without recursion is extremely difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really figure out your code, but if you're going to
backtrack (and you have to to solve Sudoku), you really should
be using recursion.  Without it, you have to simulate it; most
importantly, you won't be able to use a `for` loop, since at
times, you'll have to decrement.

Another point: I think you'll find it much simpler (especially
if you're not using recursion) if you represent the Sudoku board
as a simple linear array, `char [81]` or something like that.
If you do that, you will have a single current location index,
which you can decrement and increment, without all of the worry
of rows and columns.

So, recursive:

```
void
Puzzle::solve( int currentPosition = 0 )
{
    if ( currentPosition >= 81 ) {
        solved = true;
    } else if ( board[ currentPosition ] != empty ) {
        solve( currentPosition + 1 );
    } else {
        for ( int newValue = 1; ! solved && newValue <= 9; ++ newValue ) {
            if ( isLegal( currentPosition, newValue ) ) {
                set( currentPosition, newValue );
                solve( currentPosition + 1 );
                if ( ! solved ) {
                    unset( currentPosition );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This supposes that the board itself is a member of Puzzle, and
that Puzzle also contains a flag to tell you when you've found
a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Unfortunately, I can't change the grid and I can only use stacks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all the help!. I have figured out what my problem was. My lines were simply rearranged wrong.

```
 Address previouslocation = locations.top(); //stores the previous location from the stack
 Possibles previouspossible(grid,previouslocation); //creates a new array of new possibles
 previouspossible.array[grid[previouslocation.row][previouslocation.col]-'0'] = false;
 grid[previouslocation.row][previouslocation.col] = '*'; //changes the previous location back to empty
 possvalue = previouspossible.GetNextPossible(grid[previouslocation.row[previouslocation.col]-'0'); //gets the new possible value from new possibles
```

is supposed to be:

```
Address previouslocation = locations.top(); //stores the previous location from the stack
Possibles previouspossible(grid,previouslocation); //creates a new array of new possibles
possvalue = previouspossible.GetNextPossible(grid[previouslocation.row][previouslocation.col]-'0'); //gets the new possible value from new possibles. the '0' is to convert char to int
grid[previouslocation.row][previouslocation.col] = '*'; //changes the previous location back to empty
```

haha. Thanks again for all the help guys.